# Using postMessage in a Chrome Custom Tabs CustomTabsSession

Tags: postmessage, chrome-custom-tabs, trusted-web-activity

I'm getting to grips with the functionality available in Chrome Custom Tabs and I'm curious to know how I might go about communicating between the Custom Tab and the app itself. I can see in `CustomTabsSession` that there are methods like `requestPostMessageChannel`, but it returns `false` every time I try to use it. I also can't find any documentation or examples about this.

Does anyone know how I'd go about successfully establishing a message channel between my native code and my Custom Tabs client? Bonus question: is it possible to postMessage to a service worker?

Answer (score 3):

I just found the following Chromium patch from 2018:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/20891520570f780b13ae9725d9aa5a909338d0a9%5E%21/

> Disable PostMessage on Trusted Web Activities.
>
> Moving Trusted Web Activities over to CustomTabActivity gets us
>   PostMessage for free. Unfortunately we're not ready to launch that, so
>   disable it for the time being.

It's possible that things have changed since then, but [this flag in Chrome 81](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/tags/81.0.4027.2/chrome/browser/android/chrome_feature_list.cc#592) suggests it hasn't. So it might just not be possible to do this right now.

Comment: may I know have you used this functionality to receive post messages?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, the functionality is disabled.